# Get changed files using gitpython

Tags: python, gitpython

I want to get a list of changed files of the current git-repo. The files, that are normally listed under `Changes not staged for commit:` when calling `git status`.

So far I have managed to connected to the repository, pulled it and show all untracked files:

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo(pk_repo_path)
o = self.repo.remotes.origin
o.pull()[0]
print(repo.untracked_files)
```

But now I want to show all files, that have changes (not commited). Can anybody push me in the right direction? I looked at the names of the methods of `repo` and experimented for a while, but I can't find the correct solution.

Obviously I could call `repo.git.status` and parse the files, but that isn't elegant at all. There must be something better.

---

Edit: Now that I think about it. More usefull would be a function, that tells me the status for a single file. Like:

```
print(repo.get_status(path_to_file))
>>untracked
print(repo.get_status(path_to_another_file))
>>not staged
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get staged files using GitPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959425/how-to-get-staged-files-using-gitpython)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
for item in repo.index.diff(None):
    print(item.a_path)
```

or to get just the list:

```
changedFiles = [item.a_path for item in repo.index.diff(None)]
```

`repo.index.diff()` returns `git.diff.Diffable` described in http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.diff

So the function can look like this:

```
def get_status(repo, path):
    changed = [item.a_path for item in repo.index.diff(None)]
    if path in repo.untracked_files:
        return "untracked"
    elif path in changed:
        return "modified"
    else:
        return "don't care"
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to pass `HEAD` instead of `None` to `diff` function ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz The documentation says that `None` means to compare against the working tree, see http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=diffable#git.diff.Diffable.diff

Comment: This does not return new added files @BartBiczBoży

Comment: I have not been able to get a list of files that changed since the last pull using this method.

Comment: same here, not returning anythin

Answer (score 6):

just to catch up on @ciasto piekarz question: depending on what you want to show:

```
repo.index.diff(None)
```

does only list files that **have not** been staged

```
repo.index.diff('Head')
```

does only list files that **have** been staged