# Where to host html files on with python?

Tags: python, hosting, netlify

I am trying to find a domain to host .html files that are generated in a python project I have made. I am looking for a place where I can host an updated html file every 60 seconds (generated by my project) via an API. I have tried the following options:

1.**[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/):** Drop box offers a very simple hosting system where you can just edit files in a folder shared with dropbox, and the dropbox app will do the rest of the work for you! Surprisingly, this feature is not limited in the number of times you access it. Unfortunately though, displaying html files in dropbox is a bit slow.

2.**[Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)** Netlify will automatically host a given Github repository if it can be displayed as a webpage for free. Unfortunately, from my testing it seems Netlify only will check your github repository about once every hour

Comment: Does it need to be non-local?

Comment: You could use Amazon S3 or any service like it.

Comment: @AriK Well it needs to be displayed for a few people to use. I have it running on AWS right now, so in theory I use django and host it there but thought I would try APIs first as they should be easier.

Comment: Thanks @tadman I will have a look at Amazon S3 now

Comment: Just updating this, I mentioned AWS in my comment but was naively referring to an Amazon Workspace. Running your python project as a backed on a server is definitely the most efficient way to run it. However for those who don't want to get into setting up servers, domains and SSL Netlify is a nice quick work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netlify can be used to build files from a github repository into a website. If automatic build is turned on, the site can be updated with a push any location, including the Github Python API.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071841/how-to-push-local-files-to-github-using-python-or-post-a-commit-via-python) for an example of how to commit and push to a Github repository with the python API, thus updating a website from python.